# Scala: How to use non-simple default values?

Tags: scala, default-value

I'm new to scala and I have a class that normally only requires a handful of variables (sometimes none) to be initialized with non-default values. Initially I used a builder class to do this, but have since realized that it's better accomplished using scala's default value in the constructor. The problem is that some of the default values are a little more complex than `String = "name"` or `Int = 1` etc. and require actual code, like

```
val name: String = "Party-" + LocalDateTime.now.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toEpochSecond
```

Ok, so that looks pretty terrible, but it will satisfy a unique name requirement on that variable and it works.

I have other variables that requires a formatted date and the default value needs to be from today, something that will satisfy:

```
private val now: LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.now()
private val dateFormat: DateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")
private var startDate = dateFormat.format(now)
private var startHour = now.getHour
```

<strike>So obviously I can't use all that code as the default value of `startDate`</strike> I can't use a single line for both of these variables as they share a previously initialized variable, so how should I go about implementing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is unclear. You say "obviously I can't use all that code as the default value of `startDate`", but there is nothing obvious about this at all. I am guessing that this is homework, and there is some restriction that says you are not allowed to use compound expressions to initialize the variable? Or your company style guide forbids it? Either way, you need to tell us *in the question* what *exactly* those restrictions are, because they are in no way "obvious".

Comment: Fair enough, I'm updated my question. Of course it's possible to use a compound expression, as I've stated above with a different variable, I just feel like there might be a better way to do it because if I can't then I'm forced to use a builder because of a single variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking on it on the wrong way. Scala is a strong type language. So the best practice that to use everything as a type , so just create a case class. for your example in the long string. create a PartyEpoc, which in this case class ctor - by default has this value, otherwise will init to something else

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense because I was clearly missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this suits your use case, but would lazy values solve your problem?

```
private val now: LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.now()
private val dateFormat: DateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")
private lazy val startDate = dateFormat.format(now)
private lazy val startHour = now.getHour
```

Then you only need to initialize `now` at object construction time, and the other variables will be properly initialized when first used.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use `var` to initialize something with a default value. Mutability is generall discouraged.

Better use an `Option` on the "real" value and do a `getOrElse` to fall back to the default if the "real" one is not available. The parameter to `getOrElse` can be a block, like this:

```
myReal.getOrElse {
  val now: LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.now()
  val dateFormat: DateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")
  dateFormat.format(now)
}
```

Comment: The code you see is a part of a builder class, so using a var is required. Also, this doesn't answer my question

Comment: @EladStern var is not required for builders. You can just return a new object after each method call.